# Cannot connect to Virtual mySQL server running on Fedora 25

Tags: mysql, virtualbox, fedora

Trying to connect to my virtual MySQL server (VirtualBox Fedora 25) on mySQL workbench.

I am using the root user, yes I know this is not the most secure but for my testing it is fine.

There is a ton of information on the web on this, but all the stuff I read does not work for me.

During install of mySQL I allowed remote connections to the root user.

**So I have granted the root user all privileges using:**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
```

I flushed `PRIVILEGES` after as well

**I added a line to my**

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf

bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

**I also opened a port**

```
shell> iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
shell> iptables-save
```

I am typing the inet ip address I see under 
ifconfig into mysql workbench.

Am I doing anything wrong? or Did i miss a step?

I get error saying "cannot connect to mysql database (10060) after a long pause.

The ip-address on the virtual server is the same as one that is listed as 'unknown' on my connected devices router admin page.

Comment: It would be helpful if you had told us if you can get any network connection onto the vm, and if you had included the whole firewall config rather than just one, rather strange, line.

Comment: @symcbean alright pretty new to all this stuff, ill try getting the whole firewall config or something more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands worked!

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mysql
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

The "cannot connect to mysql database (10060)" indicates it's not an authentication problem.

Try `nc -v mysqlserver_ip_address 3306`.  It should say 'Ncat: Connected to ...'  If it does, that means you've got a TCP connection, so the problem is in mysql or the workbench.  If it says something else, the network stuff is broken or the server isn't listening on that port.

I suspect you've got a firewall dropping your packets.  A long pause usually indicates dropped packets, rather than a rejected connection.  If you connect to a non-firewalled but non-open port, the server will send you a rejection pretty quickly.  The vast majority of the time, if the connection times out it's because something is dropping the packets on the floor, rather than politely rejecting them (politeness being pretty silly when dealing with people portscanning your box).  This is something firewalls often do.  So, it's most likely a firewall thing.

You say you ran `iptables -A ....`, that would put your new line at the end of the rules, which means it probably won't be used because there's probably a default -j DROP rule that was at the end before you added that rule.  Also, iptables-save should just print out the config to stdout and not actually save the firewall config in the right place.

Try `iptables -L` to see if the ordering is wrong.  If it is, you can play around with `-I`.  An easier way to do it though, is do `iptables-save > some_temp_file`, then edit some_temp_file, and then run `iptables-restore < some_temp_file`.

If you do get the firewall working the way you want, do `iptables-save > /etc/wherever_it_goes`.  On fedora/redhat/centos that would be `iptables save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

Comment: -v mysqlserver_ip_address 3306 does say "Ncat: Connected to".  So I got a TCP connect as you said. pretty new to all this stuff, so ill look into that firewall stuff.

Comment: under mysql > status   the connection is localhost via unix socket. Should that be that?

Comment: They're on the same box?  Yes, definitely use unix socket.